# How to insert a loop block/statement after scanf

Tags: c, loops, scanf

My code is below. I am using C language. I want to repeat the action from the start if the user types Y but I am confused how can I make that happen. I tried to look for a solution but the results are not what I wanted. What should I do about it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int A,B;
char Y, N, C;

        printf("Enter value 1: ");
        scanf("%i", &B);
        printf("\nEnter value 2: ");
        scanf("%i", &A);

printf("= %i", A+B);

printf("\n\nAdd again? Y or N\n");
scanf("%c", &C);

if (C==Y){
    This should contain code that will repeat the action again.
}
else if(C==N){
    printf("PROGRAM USE ENDED.");
}
else{
    printf("Error.");
}
}
```

Comment: You can create a function which contains the logic of adding the two values and call this function in a while loop and break the loop when user enters N.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `do while` loop that checks if pressed key is `y` or not

```
int main(void) {
float x,y,sum;
char ch;
do {
printf ("Enter the first number:");
scanf ("%f",&x);
printf ("Enter the second number:");
scanf ("%f",&y);
sum=x+y;
printf ("The total number is:%f\n",sum);
printf ("Do you want to repeat the operation Y/N: ");
scanf (" %c", &ch);
}
while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
}
```